# Why does Mongo IQueryable throw InvalidOperationException when applying $filter against ExtraElements via OData?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, odata, mongodb-.net-driver

Trying to integrate Microsoft OData v4 stack with Mongo C# Driver.  I would like to expose a Mongo collection and enable the OData $filter operation against the fields contained in the ExtraElements dictionary.

I have created a minimal example of the issue. Beginning with an empty WebAPI project in Visual Studio 2015, I created the following model:

```
  public class TestEntity
  {
    [BsonId, BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string _id { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonExtraElements]
    public Dictionary<string, object> ExtraElements { get; set; }
  }
```

I exposed EDM EntitySet via OData by adding the following at the end of `WebApiConfig.Register()` method:

```
  // OData
  var edmBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
  edmBuilder.EntitySet<TestEntity>("test");

  config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", edmBuilder.GetEdmModel());
```

Finally, I created a simple TestController:

```
  public class TestController : ODataController
  {
    [EnableQuery(AllowedFunctions = Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.AllowedFunctions.All)]
    public IQueryable<TestEntity> Get()
    {
      var mongo = new MongoClient();
      var db = mongo.GetDatabase("test");
      var collection = db.GetCollection<TestEntity>("test");
      var result = collection.AsQueryable() as IQueryable<TestEntity>;
      return result;
    }
  }
```

I added an actual object to the Mongo collection:

```
> db.test.insert( {Id:'test', Name:'testName'})                                                   WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.find()
```

> { "_id" : ObjectId("5c266040fd7e5a3c63b33cd8"), "Id" : "test", "Name" : "testName" }

Now I can query find as long as I don't try to use $filter on the ExtraElements:

http://localhost:63927/odata/test

```
{"@odata.context":"http://localhost:63927/odata/$metadata#test","value":[{"Id":"test","Name":"testName","_id":"5c266040fd7e5a3c63b33cd8"}]}
```

However, if I try to filter against the `Name` (one of the `ExtraElements`) the following error occurs:

http://localhost:63927/odata/test?$filter=Name%20eq%20%27testName%27

```
Message: Convert(IIF((({document}{ExtraElements} != null) AndAlso {document}{ExtraElements}.ContainsKey(\"Name\")), {document}{ExtraElements}.Item[\"Name\"], null)) is not supported.

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException

Stack Trace:
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.GetFieldExpression(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateComparison(Expression variableExpression, ExpressionType operatorType, ConstantExpression constantExpression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslateWhere(WhereExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.TranslatePipeline(PipelineExpression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.QueryableTranslator.Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry, ExpressionTranslationOptions translationOptions)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryProviderImpl`1.Execute(Expression expression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.MongoQueryableImpl`2.GetEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.Serialization.ODataResourceSetSerializer.WriteResourceSet(IEnumerable enumerable, IEdmTypeReference resourceSetType, ODataWriter writer, ODataSerializerContext writeContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.ODataOutputFormatterHelper.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, IEdmModel model, ODataVersion version, Uri baseAddress, MediaTypeHeaderValue contentType, IWebApiUrlHelper internaUrlHelper, IWebApiRequestMessage internalRequest, IWebApiHeaders internalRequestHeaders, Func`2 getODataMessageWrapper, Func`2 getEdmTypeSerializer, Func`2 getODataPayloadSerializer, Func`1 getODataSerializerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()
```

If I add a property such as `public string Name { get; set; }` to the `TestEntity` class then the filtering will work as expected, however, I am seeking a solution which allows filtering on the BsonExtraElements.

Comment: you can use filter() method on BsonExtraElement feature filtering like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603151/how-to-query-bsonextraelements-in-mongodb-via-linq/46096062

Comment: @dewelloper Since the LINQ query is generated by the OData provider when the $filter is provided in the query string, I don't believe the referenced question or answers are applicable to my situation, can you elaborate on that further?